# Zito.Register. __struct__/1 is undefined cannot expand struct

Tags: phoenix-framework

i get the following error whenever i run the mix phoenix.server command. Below is my user.ex model, register_controller.ex and my repo files. Seems to have a problem with my model but i cant really figure what it is.

user.ex

```
defmodule Zito.User do
  use Zito.Web, :model

  schema "users" do
    field :email, :string
    field :crypted_password, :string

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc """
  Builds a changeset based on the `struct` and `params`.
  """
  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:email, :crypted_password])
    |> validate_required([:email, :crypted_password])
    |> validate_format(:email, ~r/@/)
    |> validate_length(:crypted_password, min: 8)
    |> validate_length(:crypted_password, max: 16)

  end
end
(code)
```

register_controller.ex

```
defmodule Zito.RegisterController do
    use Zito.Web, :controller

    alias Zito.Register

    def create(conn, %{"register" => register_params}) do
        changeset = Register.changeset(%Register{}, register_params)

        case Zito.Register.create(changeset, Zito.Repo) do
        {:ok, changeset} ->
          conn
          |> put_flash(:info, "Your account was created")
          |> redirect(to: "/")
        {:error, changeset} ->
          conn
          |> put_flash(:info, "Unable to create account")
          |> render("register.html", changeset: changeset)
      end
    end
end
```

and my repo file

```
defmodule Zito.Repo.Migrations.CreateUser do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:users) do
      add :email, :string
      add :crypted_password, :string

      timestamps()
    end
    create unique_index(:users, [:email])
  end
end
```

Comment: The model you've posted is called `User` and you're using `%Register{}` and `Register.changeset` in the controller that you've posted?

Comment: @Dogbert av changed the model name of the file to `register.ex` still getting the same error

Comment: You changed the module name or file name? The file name doesn't matter; you need the correct module name.

Comment: @Dogbert thanks i made changes its now working well